# How to get last rows from google sheets with c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to get last 100 rows from my google table with c# Google.Apis.Sheets.v4. Also i'd like to be able to get all rows with column A value greater than 120. Is there a way to do this without loading all the rows from table into memory to filter them?

Comment: Spreadsheets aren't database tables. Have you tried specifying a range? Or a filter? If you can do something in the Google Sheets application, you can probably do this in C# as well

Comment: ranges are not flexible enough for me. Because if i want to get last X rows i need to know total rows count which i don't know how to get. Also I'd like to keep data into sheets table clean, so i don't want to inject query right there. Is there a way for me?

Comment: Sheets aren't tables, they're spreadsheets. If you want the service to filter and return the data you need to use them as spreadsheets. You can ask the number of rows without actually retrieving all rows. If you get 600 rows you can construct a range eg `A500:...` to retrieve the last 100 rows. Sheets also allow specifying [filters](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters) and even creating filters in advance and applying them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get last 100 rows from my google table with c# Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.

- There is currently no way to get this information directly using Sheets API.
- However, to workaround this you can declare a generic range on your request to Sheets API. For example, to fetch the entire column A starting at the 500th row, you can use `A500:A`.

> Also i'd like to be able to get all rows with column A value greater than 120. Is there a way to do this without loading all the rows from table into memory to filter them?

- Same scenario, Sheets API currently doesn’t support a “conditional fetch”. You must fetch a range of cells and treat the cells values in your script.